# NotNullWhen(bool) not working as expected

Tags: c#

I have a function like this

```cs
public bool GetRes([NotNullWhen(false)] out SomeEnum? error, [NotNullWhen(true)] out int[]? res)
{
     error = _error;
     res = _res;
     return _error == null;
}
```

Then, I use it like this..

```cs
if (!GetRes(out var error, out var res))
{
      // trying to use error but it says cannot convert SomeEnum? to SomeEnum
}

// But can use 'res' here. It says 'res' is not null here
```

My .proj is like this

```xml
<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Comment: Nullable analysis attributes don't work on value types, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Sweeper [They absolutely do](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Comment: [reproduction](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=)

Comment: @ertucode Well yes. You declared `error` as a `SomeEnum?`. Since `SomeEnum` is a value type, that's just syntactic sugar for `Nullable<SomeEnum>`. You can't assign a value of type `Nullable<SomeEnum>` to a variable of type `SomeEnum`. You need to access its `.Value` property, e.g. `error.Value`. This has nothing to do with `NotNullWhen`

Comment: @canton7 `res` is not a value type...

Comment: @Sweeper `error` is, and see the nullable warning when you access `error.Value` in the case where `GetRes` returns true

Comment: @canton7 Ah I didn't know `error.Value` would have produced a warning. TIL.

Comment: @ertucode [See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgygewLYFMCiUJIPwAIBmCCuAvLoqhlgHQCCA3ALABQF6mSuARgIZikEiTZiwACAZlwoO5ZOyy4A3rloAaXACFcAX3pA==) for a simpler case of the same thing

Comment: But I can use `.Value` even if the value is null so it doesn't help. I guess using `NotNullWhen` with value types is useless

Comment: @ertucode The caller gets a warning if they access `.Value` in the case where `error` can be null. See the link I sent to Sweeper above

Comment: I see, but visual studio is not giving me any warning inside or outside of the scope.

Comment: @ertucode You should get a warning, see that SharpLab link. Put that exact code into VS, see whether you get a warning.

Comment: It shows the error sometimes. Great IDE

Comment: @ertucode Does it not show the error in the `Output` window? (Note that you can add `<WarningsAsErrors>CS8602, CS8629</WarningsAsErrors>` to your project file to force the compile to actually fail for those kinds of warnings.)

Comment: I don't know what is the `Output` window but if you are talking about the window that I can open after searching for output, and it says `Show output from: Build`, that window doesn't show anything. And the warning squiggles show sometimes. Then if I edit it a bit, or hit tab and shifttab for a bit, the warning dissapear until I edit again and it feels like showing me the warning.

Comment: It shows in View->Error List after I right click on the project and run `Analyze and Code Cleanup -> Run Code Analysis`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NotNullWhen` does work correctly with nullable structs once you've corrected the use of the `error` nullable struct (which is of underlying type `Nullable<SomeEnum>`).

Consider the following corrected code:

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (!GetRes(out var error, out var res))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Value);
            Console.WriteLine(res.Length); // Warning: "Dereference of a possibly null reference".
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Value); // Warning: "Nullable value type may be null".
            Console.WriteLine(res.Length);
        }
    }

    public static bool GetRes([NotNullWhen(false)] out SomeEnum? error, [NotNullWhen(true)] out int[]? res)
    {
        if (Environment.TickCount == 0)
        {
            res   = Array.Empty<int>();
            error = null;
            return true;
        }

        error = SomeEnum.A;
        res = null;
        return false;
    }
}

public enum SomeEnum { A, B };
```

You will get a compiler warning as noted by the comments in `Main()`.

In particular, note the warning for the access to `error.Value`.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that `SomeEnum` is a value type. Unlike nullable reference types, which are just syntax and don't change the underlying types used by the CLR, nullable value types are actual types.

So `SomeEnum?` is actually a shorthand for `Nullable<SomeEnum>`. You can't implicitly assign `Nullable<SomeEnum>` to a variable of type `SomeEnum`. Either call `.Value` or use an explicit conversion `(SomeEnum)`.

Comment: But the caller can use `.Value` without checking for the returned bool. So the return type doesnt give the caller any information.

Comment: Actually the compiler was supposed to be giving me warnings but visual studio was being stupid.

Comment: `I assume that SomeEnum is a value type.` - isn't it fair to say that `SomeEnum` is an `Enum`

Comment: @RandRandom Yes, in a sane world. But the OP didn't specify so technically `SomeEnum` could have been a class instead of an enum. :)

Comment: @ertucode I don't understand what you mean by checking for the returned bool. Calling `.Value` doesn't in and of itself guarantee that the operation will be successful. It will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if it turns out the value is null and you haven't checked. The `NotNullWhen` attribute should ensure that the compiler doesn't give you warnings if you check the return value of `GetRes` instead of checking `error` for null directly. But it's not a guarantee if you don't trust the person who wrote `GetRes`. They could have a bug and set `error` to null when the method returns false.

Comment: I was saying that being able to use `.Value` was not helpful since it does not indicate if it will be succesful. But apparently my IDE was acting up and I cant use `.Value` if I dont check the returned value. I thought I could use `.Value` without checking.

Comment: @ertucode You can, but you probably shouldn't because it could throw an exception at run time. The compiler will give you a warning about it when building. Checking will remove the warning, either directly using `error != null` or `error.HasValue`, or indirectly through checking something else linked through nullability attributes, like `NotNullWhen` which you used.